# How to return the amount of rows deleted (delete all statement) in a function?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm currently trying to create a function in pl/sql which deletes all Customer rows from the Customer table, then return the value of the total rows deleted. Then a procedure is meant to run this through, however currently the result I get in the DOPL (when successful) is "Deleting all customer rows rows deleted", how can I change it so the DOPL in the procedure return the amount of rows deleted value in the function e.g. "5 rows deleted"

Here is my current code (thanks in advance):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DELETE_ALL_CUSTOMERS_FROM_DB RETURN NUMBER 
AS vCount NUMBER;
BEGIN
     DELETE FROM Customer;
     RETURN vCount;
EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, SQLERRM);
END;
 /

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DELETE_ALL_CUSTOMERS_VIASQLDEV AS
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('--------------------------------------------');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Deleting all Customer rows');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DELETE_ALL_CUSTOMERS_FROM_DB || ' rows deleted');
COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
END;
 /
```

Comment: You're not writing MySQL code so please don't use the  `[mysql]` tag.

Comment: Apologies :( Will not add this next time, is there a way I can remove the tag from this post?

Comment: You can edit your own questions.

Comment: Oh yep can see it now - looks like you went ahead and changed it - thank you! Sorry, bit of a SO noob.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not populating the `v_count` variable with anything so it returns a null.

There is an Oracle built-in, `SQL%ROWCOUNT` which gives the number of rows affected by the preceding DML statement. So you simply need to change your deleting function to this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DELETE_ALL_CUSTOMERS_FROM_DB
 RETURN NUMBER 
AS 
BEGIN
     DELETE FROM Customer;
     RETURN sql%rowcount;
EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) Just for a learning's sake, could you also do this using a variable?

Comment: Of course you can assign `sql%rowcount` to a variable